# How to select first and last name initials on MySQL

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm new to MySQL and I'm trying to learn how create a query that selects the first & last names initials from a list of names on a table. For example. say I have a table named 'people' and has someone called 'John Dow' his initials would be J.D, I'm not sure how to go about this since what can find here only covers how to use the 'LIKE','SUBSTRING' or 'LEFT' operators to select the first letter of a name but it displays the full name, not the initials.

Thank you

Comment: It's hard if the name is stored as a full name, something that might cover a lot of cases would be just to get the first and last word in the full name and get the first letter of those.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then you may make use of the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function.  Consider this approach:

```sql
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 'John Dow' AS name UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Ludwig Amadeus Mozart'
)

SELECT name, REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '([A-Z])[a-z]+\\s*', '$1.') AS initials
FROM t;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The regex pattern `([A-Z])[a-z]+\\s*` targets each component of the name, capturing only the leading first letter.  It matches, but does not capture, the rest of the lowercase letters in the name, along with any optional trailing whitespace.

Comment: This is very interesting. However it seems that this would only apply it to one name at a time and not the entire name list, is that correct?

Comment: @Odez It would do a regex replacement on however many names appear in the column, as my code and demo are showing.